# Relationship between the averages of a concave function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis

I have two functions $S^m(K)$ and $S^f(K)$, such that $S^m(K)$ > $S^f(K)$ $\forall K>0$.

Also, $S_K(K) >0$ and $S_{KK}(K) <0$, making the functions increasing and concave.

Also, $S^m_{K}(K)$ > $S^f_{K}(K)$ $\forall K >0$.

Values $K^1 > 0$ and $K^2 > 0$ are such that $K^1 > K^2$ and  $K^1 + K^2 \leq \bar{K}$.

If $$\frac{S^m(K^1)}{K^1} \geq \frac{S^f(K^2)}{K^2} $$ is $$S^m_{K}(K^1) \geq S^f_{K}(K^2). $$

Is the reverse true as well?

I've tried manipulating the expressions algebraically and using the Jensen's inequality, but to no avail. Please help me.

Comment: Is there missing something? According to your question, the numerators are equal and since $K^1>K^2$ the fraction on the left is strictly smaller than the one on the right.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, the last line should be comparing averages and not first derivatives. I've edited my post.

Comment: Is there still missing something? Suppose the $\geq$ was not true and the LHS is smaller than the RHS. Then we could define another function $S^o(K)=S^m(K)+C$ where $C>0$ is a constant. $S^o$ and $S^f$ satisfy the conditions of your question too. Choosing $C$ large enough guarantees that $\geq$ is true. But this doesn't prove that the inequality holds in general.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid your conditions are way too general for us to be able to comment definitively. If $K_1 < K_2$, the result you claim holds by concavity. If not, it depends on the derivatives of the two functions. For instance, note that if we fix $K_2$, then there exists $\hat{K}_1$ such that $S^m(\hat{K}_1) = (S^f(K_2)/K_2)\hat{K}_1$; for any $K > \hat{K}_1$, $S^m(K)/K < S^f(K_2)/K_2$, so we need to only consider $K_1 < \hat{K}_1$. Similarly, define $\tilde{K}$ by the equation $S^m(\tilde{K}) - S^f(K_2) = S^f_K(K_2)(\tilde{K} - K_2)$. In general, we could have $\hat{K}_1 < \tilde{K}$ or $\tilde{K} < \hat{K}_1$. When $\tilde{K}>\hat{K}_1$ your result holds, since $S^m_K > S^f_K$ for all values of K where the upper inequality holds. The result can fail if $\hat{K}_1 > \tilde{K}$. Suppose $S^m_K(\hat{K}_1) < S^f_K(K_2)$. Then there may exist a $K' \in (\tilde{K}, \hat{K}_1)$ such that the upper inequality holds (since $K' < \hat{K}_1$), but $S^m_K(K') < S^f_K(K_2)$. Overall, I agree with Elsa: this isn't a meaningful result unless we have some more conditions on the two functions.